# How do I access depth data in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've seen shaders that create an outline around edges dynamically based on how much difference there is between the depth (distance from camera to surface) of a pixel at an edge and the depth of a pixel adjacent to it (less depth can mean a thinner outline or none at all). Like these renders:

[image]

[image]

And I'm interested in using such a shader on my three.js renders, but I think I need to figure out how to access depth data for each pixel.

Three.js documentation [mentions a depth setting](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.depth):

> depth - whether the drawing buffer has a depth buffer of at least 16
>   bits. Default is true.

But I'm not sure what it means by the drawing buffer having a depth buffer. The image buffers I'm familiar with are pixel buffers, with no depth information. Where would I access this depth buffer at?

Answer (score 4):

There's [an example in the Three.js website](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=depth#webgl_depth_texture) that renders the scene to a `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget` with it's `depthBuffer` attribute set to `true`. This gives you access to depth data.

The idea is as follows:

1. Render the main scene to a `WebGLRenderTarget`. This target will contain RGB and Depth data that can be accessed via their [`.texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget.texture) and [`.depthTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget.depthTexture) attributes, accordingly.
2. Take these 2 textures, and apply them to a plane with custom shaders.
3. In the plane's custom shaders, you can access the texture data to perform whatever calculations you want to play with colors and depth.
4. Render the second scene (that contains only the plane) to canvas.

[Here's the link to source code of that example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_depth_texture.html) Notice you can comment-out the code on line 73 to allow the color data to display.

Comment: Just a note, it'd be good to identify which line of code line 73 is. By now line 73 is whitespace. There are two ways to do that. You could include a snippet here or (better) make your link to github point at the specific commit you were referencing (rather than `.../blob/master/...`). Then a line number reference does not become stale. Furthermore you can make a link to github code that embeds emphasis on a line or a range of lines! (with appending e.g. `#L71-L74` on the url, you can obtain this url by clicking a line number).

Answer (score 0):

Three.js already has a MeshToonMaterial, there's no need to create a new one.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_variations_toon.html

```css
html, body, iframe {margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:0}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_variations_toon.html">
```

Comment: This is nice information but is an alternative, not an answer. What if I want my edges to behave differently (control thickness, how the edges taper when the edge ends, etc), or have their color based on nearby pixel color? I doubt this material gives all the control a designer might want for their render style.

Comment: Agree 100%. Do you need any of those? Maybe adding these options to the current existing shader toon material would be easier. You can check ou the source code here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/ShaderToon.js

Comment: I kind of just want to start from scratch for the challenge anyway, I just need to find the way to access depth data as a buffer

Comment: Seems like the current toon material does this with the vertex shader at line 41 https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/ShaderToon.js#L41 `vec3 I = worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition;`